# Haskell LLVM problem I dont know what to do

Tags: haskell

so i wanted to learn haskell but after seting it up and trying to run my code this error
is shows up

```
 <no location info>: error:
Warning: Couldn't figure out LLVM version!
         Make sure you have installed LLVM between [9 and 13) ghc: could not execute: opt
```

it says it dosent have LLVM but I dont know how to install it
or what it is

Comment: LLVM is the compiler backend, for which Haskell/GHC is just one client out of many. Full details at www.llvm.org. You did not specify which sort of environment you have. For example, if it is an RPM-based Linux distro, the command to install LLVM is typically something like: `dnf install llvm llvm-libs llvm-devel`

Comment: Please, specify details: Installation Source, Environment (Operating System etc.), sufficiently, so that one can understand what you did and reconstruct.
Ask yourself: What does one have to do to get the same error message?